# Symfony Multiple Entity Managers not found error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two bundle main AppBundle and PrestaShopConnectionBundle to get information from PrestaShop datebase.
When I'm trying to get information from ProductShop entity I got error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'prestashop.ps_product_shop' doesn't exist
```

command

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --em=prestashop
```

return "Nothing to update" so it is probably detected table from PrestaShop.
But why controller can't get date from it?

```
<?php
//src/PrestaShopConnectionBundle/Entity/ProductShop.php
namespace PrestaShopConnectionBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="prestashop.ps_product_shop")
 */
class ProductShop
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_product")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=20, scale=6, name="price")
     * @ORM\Column()
     */
    protected $price;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param string $price
     * @return ProductShop
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }
}



    <?php
//src/PrestaShopConnectionBundle/Entity/ProductShop.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use PrestaShopConnectionBundle\Entity\ProductShop;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/app/example", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $product = $this->get('doctrine')
        ->getRepository('PrestaShopConnectionBundle:ProductShop', 'prestashop')
        ->findAll();

        dump($product);

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

config.yml

```
    imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
        less:
            node: /usr/bin/node
            node_paths: [/usr/lib/node_modules]

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
          default:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
          prestashop:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     "%database_shop_host%"
            port:     "%database_shop_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_shop_name%"
            user:     "%database_shop_user%"
            password: "%database_shop_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
            mapping_types: 
              enum:       string


    orm:
      default_entity_manager: default
      auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
      entity_managers:
            default:
              connection: default
              naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
              mappings:
                AppBundle:  ~
                PrestaShopConnectionBundle: ~
            prestashop:
              connection: prestashop
              naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
              mappings:
                PrestaShopConnectionBundle: ~


# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

mopa_bootstrap:
    form:
        show_legend: false # default is true
        show_child_legend: false # default is true
        error_type: block # or inline which is default
```

Comment: `@ORM\Table(name="prestashop.ps_product_shop")` <- I dont think this is supposed to have the database name in it?

Comment: @OIS Yes, you right. Thank you. Once again I was looking for the problem in the wrong place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @OIS noted, `@ORM\Table(name="prestashop.ps_product_shop")` is bad!

I just copied from my application so it should work fine if you can adopt into yours.

**parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
    database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    database_host:     127.0.0.1
    database_port:     ~
    database_name:     abc_dev
    database_user:     dev
    database_password: mysqlpassword
    database_path:     ~

    def_database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    def_database_host:     127.0.0.1
    def_database_port:     ~
    def_database_name:     def_dev
    def_database_user:     dev
    def_database_password: mysqlpassword
    def_database_path:     ~
```

**config.yml**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: abc
        connections:
          abc:
            driver:   %database_driver%
            host:     %database_host%
            port:     %database_port%
            dbname:   %database_name%
            user:     %database_user%
            password: %database_password%
            charset:  UTF8

            mapping_types:
                enum: string

          def:
            driver:   %def_database_driver%
            host:     %def_database_host%
            port:     %def_database_port%
            dbname:   %def_database_name%
            user:     %def_database_user%
            password: %def_database_password%
            charset:  UTF8

            mapping_types:
                enum: string

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        default_entity_manager: abc

        entity_managers:
            abc:
              connection: abc
              mappings:
                  ApplicationAbcBundle:
                    dir:  Entity/Abc
            def:
              connection: def
              mappings:
                  ApplicationDefBundle:
                    dir:  Entity/Def
```

**application structure**

```
src
    Application
        AbcBundle
            Entity
                Abc
                    your entities....
        DefBundle
            Entity
                Def
                    your entities....
```

**Example command lines**

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --em:abc --force
app/console doctrine:generate:entities ...... --em:def
```